# Magento2: Custom module not working

Tags: magento2, module, controllers, custom-block

I have created new module but it is not working.Please Help me on this.

**registration**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Outdoor_Configurator',
    __DIR__
);
```

**Module**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Outdoor_Configurator" setup_version="1.0.0">
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
         <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
        <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
        <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
        <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
    </sequence>
</module>
```

**routes**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
<router id="standard">
    <route id="testconfigurator" frontName="testconfigurator">
        <module name="Outdoor_Configurator" />
    </route>
</router>
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Controller\Index;
 class BuiltCatCollection extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
 {
/** @var  \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page */
protected $resultPageFactory;
/**      * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context      */
public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory)
{
    $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}
/**
 * Blog Index, shows a list of recent blog posts.
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
 */
public function execute()
{
    $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
    $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Custom Front View'));
    return $resultPage;
}
```

}

**Block**

```
<?php
 namespace Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Index;
 class BuiltInfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
 {
 public function _prepareLayout()
 {
    return parent::_prepareLayout();
  }
 }
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Index\BuiltInfo" name="outdoor_configurator" template="Outdoor_Configurator::builtcatcolinfo.phtml"></block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
```

**Template**

```
<span style="font-weight: 400;">This is custom front view.</span>
```

Comment: run php bin/magento mo:s to know if the module is registered and enabled. If not run php bin/magento s:up to register and php bin/magento mo:e Vendor_Module to enable it

Comment: Did you create registration.php  ??

Comment: I have checked module is enabled @VivekKumar

Comment: I have updated regitration code. Please check @RaviSoni

Comment: I have added my answer for your module. Please check where you miss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create your module like this.

> registration.php

```
    <?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Outdoor_Configurator',
    __DIR__
);
```

> etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Outdoor_Configurator" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Backend"/>
             <module name="Magento_Sales"/>
            <module name="Magento_Quote"/>
            <module name="Magento_Checkout"/>
            <module name="Magento_Cms"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="configurator" frontName="configurator">
            <module name="Outdoor_Configurator" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

> Block/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Outdoor\Configurator\Block\Index;


class Index extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template {

    public function __construct(\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context, array $data = []) {

        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }


    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

> Controller/Index/Index.php

```
<?php

namespace Outdoor\Configurator\Controller\Index;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

> view/frontend/templates/index/configurator_index_index.phtml

```
Hello Demo Page
```

> view/frontend/layout/configurator_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>Titlename</title>
    </head> 
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Outdoor\Configurator\Block\Index\Sidebar" name="configurator_index_sidebar" before="-" template="Outdoor_Configurator::configurator_index_sidebar.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>

        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Outdoor\Configurator\Block\Index\Index" name="configurator_index_index" template="Outdoor_Configurator::configurator_index_index.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Please check Now I have updated all code, with file name also.

Comment: Ok, I will check and update you.

Comment: I have created same module but not working.  got the 404 error.

Comment: Can i share you zip file?

Comment: yes, i can, but how ?

Comment: I will share you download link.

Comment: Please download zip file and check my code. https://transfernow.net/813mi1m90ghk

Comment: Module was created but phtml code is not showing. Please check link https://ibb.co/2cBKKXs

Comment: I cheking in your module, there is so many mistake, in file name, path, give me some time

Comment: Hi please check now, I have updated the code as well file name. And check in my fresh setup. It's working now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95494/discussion-between-ravi-soni-and-masud-shaikh).

Comment: Module is created successfully, Thanks!

Comment: Block rendered twice. Please help me on this.

Comment: Same data generate two times.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few problems in your module:

1. You have used **`Outdoor_Configurator`** in module.xml but in Controller, Block, and layout you have used **`Vendor_Module`**.
2. **`registration.php`** is missing from the code you have shared.
3. You have not mentioned the file names and their paths. There may be a problem in the file naming convention.

**Update:**

Problems found in module shared at https://transfernow.net/813mi1m90ghk.

- The controller file name is **Builtcatcollection.php.php**, which is wrong. Notice .php twice.
- Code under block file is the same as in the controller file.
- Folder name **`View`** should be **`view`** (small case).
- The code under layout file is wrong.

Instead of:

```
<block class="Codism\Configurator\Block\Index\Builtcatcollection" name="index.builtcatcollection" template="Outdoor_Configurator::index/builtcatcollection.phtml"/>
```

it should be like:

```
<block class="Outdoor\Configurator\Block\Index\Builtcatcollection" name="index.builtcatcollection" template="Outdoor_Configurator::index/builtcatcollection.phtml"/>
```

Comment: I have updated regitration code. Please check

Comment: @MasudShaikh, please read the first point. You have used wrong names in Controller, Block and layout files.

Comment: I have created module under Codism folder and I have gave module name Outdoor_Configurator. I think my module name should be Codism_Configurator right?

Comment: It should be either Outdoor_Configurator or Codism_Configurator. Whatever name you use, it should be same at all places.

Comment: Controller file name in your module is also wrong (Builtcatcollection.php.php).

Comment: I have gave the same name all places but module is not working.

Comment: Let me brief out the problems I have found in your module.

Comment: I have shared you zip file please check link https://transfernow.net/30k8t5o1aei3

Comment: @MasudShaikh, I have added my findings. Please check and let me know if it helped. Also, please accept my answer if you found it useful.

Comment: Module was created but phtml code is not showing. Please check link https://ibb.co/2cBKKXs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95493/discussion-between-mohit-kumar-arora-and-masud-shaikh).

Comment: Block rendered twice. Please help me

Comment: Same data generate two times.